# How to get Flash to play through HDMI

Tags: sound, flash, hdmi

I've had a litany of sound problems, in particular with Adobe Flash on Firefox. I can get most sounds to play through the TV speakers, which are connected to my Ubuntu laptop through HDMI, but I can't get Flash to do that. I can't right-click on Flash without crashing it. Just this last half hour, there was a period where Pulseaudio wasn't working, but Flash was still playing through the headphones, and then when I loaded another video Flash stopped playing sound while Pulseaudio started working again.

How do I get Flash to play through HDMI?

Comment: Do you mean FlashPlayer within Firefox or Chrome browsers? If not do you have a link to this program called "Flash"?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Changed to say Adobe Flash on Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

1. Install pavucontrol from terminal:

   `sudo apt-get install pavucontrol`
2. Go to the Firefox and play a video with sound.
3. Run pavucontrol and from playback tab you can see Firefox on the list and change the output device for that.

[image: pavucontrol]

Comment: Sound goes through my laptop speakers and not through the headphones, and I'm not seeing Firefox in Playback.

Comment: Logged out and in. Now sound works except in Flash. It works on Youtube which isn't Flash.

Comment: Your answer is wrong probably because you think the problem lies with Firefox. It's actually a problem with Flash on Firefox.

Comment: @jkabrg when you play the flash movie, can you see the audio spectrum on the playback tab? if you hear the sound you can see that on the playback tab. maybe flash movies are not on the Firefox section and they are on another thing like flash.

Comment: No, there is nothing on Playback except "System sounds".

Comment: The video is also silent for some reason. Used to not be.

Comment: @jkabrg you can not see Firefox in the list because your video is silent. you can see Firefox there only if it has sound.

Comment: Video isn't silent now. I see Firefox in `Playback` but it doesn't give me the option to change the output device

Comment: Now Flash plays through my headphones, and Youtube plays through HDMI, but I still don't get the option to change the output device.

Comment: If it does not list there at all it means your flash player does not use Pulse Audio :(